# Elegant way to add to_hash (or to_h) method to Struct?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I'm using a Struct as opposed to a simple Hash in a project to provide a semantic name to a collection of key value pairs.  Once I've built the structure, however, I need to output a hash value.  I'm in Ruby 1.9.3. Example:

```
MyMeaninfulName = Struct.new(:alpha, :beta, :gamma) do
  def to_hash
    self.members.inject({}) {|h,m| h[m] = self[m]; h}
  end
end

my_var = MyMeaningfulName.new
my_var.to_hash # -> { :alpha=>nil, :beta=>nil, :gamma=>nil }
```

Is there a reason why Struct does not include a to_hash method?  It seems like a natural fit, but perhaps there's an underlying reason why it's not included.

Second, is there a more elegant way to build a generic to_hash method into Struct (either generally, via monkeypatching, or through a module or inheritance).

Comment: To clarify the second part of the question...  Because Struct is a factory of Classes, I'm not really sure how to add the to_hash functionality (which would be easy in any traditional class).

Comment: If you want to clarify, you can edit the question -- just click the **edit** link under the question text. By the way, good question. +1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Struct
  old_new = self.method(:new)
  def self.new(*args) 
    obj = old_new.call(*args)
    obj.class_exec do
      def to_hash
        self.members.inject({}) {|h,m| h[m] = self[m]; h}
      end
    end
    return obj
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting `undefined local variable or method old_new` for Struct:Class` when I try: `class MyClass < Struct.new(:prop)`

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is about ruby 1.9.3, but starting from ruby 2.0.0, `Struct` has a [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Struct.html#method-i-to_h) method which does the job.

```
MyMeaningfulName = Struct.new(:alpha, :beta, :gamma)

my_var = MyMeaningfulName.new
my_var.to_h # -> { :alpha=>nil, :beta=>nil, :gamma=>nil }
```

Answer (score 2):

or this:

```
class Struct
  def to_hash
    self.class.members.inject({}) {|h,m| h[m] = self[m]}
  end
end
```

(note the extra class to get to the members)

Comment: I believe your inject block is missing `h` as return value; this raises an exception for me. Or use `each` and move `h` to the outer scope.

Comment: I'm torn between this answer and Linuxios'. His is more wordy but, for me, more explicit about exactly what's going on.

Comment: @GSP - agreed - shortness is not always for the best

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, it does seem obvious. Fortunately, you can use it as a hash in many places since it implements bracket operators.

Anyway, this is fairly elegant:

```
MyMeaningfulName = Struct.new :alpha, :beta, :gamma do
  def to_hash
    Hash[members.zip values]
  end
end

my_var = MyMeaningfulName.new 1, 2, 3
my_var.to_hash # => {:alpha=>1, :beta=>2, :gamma=>3}
```